# Json output s --- just print the output withou u

Tags: python, json

I am parsing a JSON output asbelow...this is just a snippet..currently it is printing the u'' format...How do i just print "deleted"

```
error=change['Errors']
print error
```

Output:

```
[u'DELETED']
```

Expected output:

```
DELETED
```

Comment: We'd like to see some code.

Comment: @thg435: There IS code in his question!

Comment: @nhahtdh: I guess it's pretty much obvious that I was asking for a [sscce](http://sscce.org/). `print error` doesn't qualify as such.

Comment: @thg435: It is not very obvious for the OP, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do when there's more than one value in `change['Errors']`. Currently the value is a list of one element (`u'DELETED'`). If you want to print just the text, you need:

```
print error[0]
```

But maybe just in case it would be better to do:

```
print u', '.join(error)
```

Comment: Then what you get in `error` is probably something that prints the same way as a list but doesn't index the same way. Check what type it is and read the docs on how to use it.

Comment: @viraptor really strange answer.

Answer (score 0):

JSON works with unicode by default. If you need another codec, you can pass an *encoding* argument to the dump function:

```
json.dumps(obj, skipkeys=False, ensure_ascii=True, check_circular=True, allow_nan=True, cls=None, indent=None, separators=None, encoding="utf-8", default=None, sort_keys=False, **kw)
```