# Converting list of strings with u'...' to a list of normal strings

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

I'm a newbie in python. And apologies for a very basic question.

I'm working with python `pattern.en` library and try to get the synonyms of a word. this is my code and is working fine.

```
from pattern.en import wordnet
a=wordnet.synsets('human')
print a[0].synonyms
```

this what the output i get from this:

```
[u'homo', u'man', u'human being', u'human']
```

but for my program i need to insert this array as this:

```
['homo', 'man', 'human being', 'human']
```

how do i get an output as above and remove the 'u' from my output.

thanks in advance..!

Comment: You mean your program needs a list of strings other than unicode strings?

Comment: no need to remove `u` from your string, it works fine same as string, `u` represents unicode string

Comment: yes exactly... and i didn't knew that u referring for Unicode.. :(

Comment: `u` is just a representation to show unicode string literals. Your strings don't actually have a u at the start. No need to remove them.

Comment: Are you working with python2 or python3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try proper [encoding](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)- But care this **`u` does not have any effect on data**- it is just an explicit representation of unicode object (not byte array), if your code needs back `unicode` then better to feed it unicode.

```
>>>d =  [u'homo', u'man', u'human being', u'human']
>>>print [i.encode('utf-8') for i in d]
>>>['homo', 'man', 'human being', 'human']
```

Comment: It works but it's not a good advice. There's no need to go back to byte array/ string representation. Since equivalence is never an issue with unicode vs str in python2 and in python3 str is by default unicode

Comment: @alvas Yes and so i mentioned it (`u does not have any effect on data`)

Comment: @Slslam hope you don't mind if i bold it =)

Answer (score 1):

**In short:**

There's no need to convert you list of unicodes into strings. They're the same thing

---

**In long:**

The `u'...'` prefix in the string object represents a Unicode object introduced in Python 2.0, see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings

> Starting with Python 2.0 a new data type for storing text data is
>   available to the programmer: the Unicode object. It can be used to
>   store and manipulate Unicode data (see http://www.unicode.org/) and
>   integrates well with the existing string objects, providing
>   auto-conversions where necessary.

And since Python 3.0, see https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/introduction.html#about-unicode:

> Starting with Python 3.0 all strings support Unicode (see
>   http://www.unicode.org/).

Regardless of what is the default string type, when checking for equivalence, they should be the same in both Python 2.x and 3.x:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ python2
Python 2.7.11 (default, Dec 15 2015, 16:46:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> type(u'man')
<type 'unicode'>
>>> type('man')
<type 'str'>
>>> u'man' == 'man'
True

alvas@ubi:~$ python3
Python 3.4.1 (default, Jun  4 2014, 11:27:44) 
[GCC 4.8.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> type(u'man')
<class 'str'>
>>> type('man')
<class 'str'>
>>> u'man' == 'man'
True
```

And in Python 2, when you **MUST** or are required to convert from `unicode` to `str` type let's say for type checks or something, e.g.:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ python3
>>> u'man' == 'man'
True
>>> type(u'man') == type('man')
True
>>> exit()
alvas@ubi:~$ python2
>>> u'man' == 'man'
True
>>> type(u'man') == type('man')
False
```

then you should be able to simply cast it to `str(u'man')` or `u'man'.encode('utf-8')`.

But there could be some "pain" / endless errors if your unicode string is out of the ascii range and you're trying to write it to file or print it onto console which might not have defaultencoding set to 'utf-8'. In that case, watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc

---

Additionally, here are similar questions relating to the `u'...'` prefix:

- [What does the 'u' symbol mean in front of string values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279331/what-does-the-u-symbol-mean-in-front-of-string-values)
- [Why is there a 'u' before every line of my output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406533/why-is-there-a-u-before-every-line-of-my-output)
- [Python string prints as [u'String']](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599625/python-string-prints-as-ustring)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855645/how-to-turn-unicode-strings-into-regular-strings
- [What's the u prefix in a python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string)
- [Printing a string prints 'u' before the string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170808/printing-a-string-prints-u-before-the-string-in-python)