# extra characters on python list

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm having an issue issue with:

```
slots = rows[i].find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
prodFolder = slots[0].text
prodType = slots[2].text
prodId = slots[1].text
values = [prodFolder, prodId, prodType]
print values
```

When I go to print values I get an extra character at the front of each item in the list: 
[u'active_e', u'1193', u'Active E']
This is probably the result of .text providing some extra data that I do not want. Is there an elegant way to solve this? (not using brute force to remove the extra u's?)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986329/converting-list-of-strings-with-u-to-a-list-of-normal-strings

Comment: It's not extra character. It's a representation of `unicode` character.

Comment: Nothing to worry about.

Comment: `values = [str(i.text) for i in slots]`. And `print values`.Change your like this.

Comment: @RahulKP this will raise a `UnicodeEncodeError` if there are any non-ascii characters in there. Use `i.text.encode('utf-8')` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `'u'` in `u'active_e'` just indicates that this is a `unicode` object, and not a bytestring. You can use `encode` to convert it:

```
> u = u'active_e'
> s = u.encode('utf-8')

> u
u'active_e'
> s
'active_e'

# But:
> print(u)
active_e
> print(s)
active_e

> type(u)
<type 'unicode'>
> type(s)
<type 'str'>
```

But in most contexts, `unicode` objects are just as fine as bytestrings. For pure ASCII strings, even `u == s` will be `True`:

```
> u == s
True

# careful with non-ascii chars:
> u = u'äöüß'
> s = u.encode('utf-8')
> u == s
False

> len(u)
4
> len(s)
8  # ä,ö,ü,ß have two-byte representations
```